# Modify Logger's adoAppender.ConnectionString

Tags: c#, log4net, dbconnection

I am using log4net. The problem is I create the connection string only after the application is started based on the connection string in the config file. This means the config file does not have a proper connection string yet. I am able to modify the connection string of the appender using this code..

```
IAppender[] appenders = log.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders();
foreach(IAppender appender in appenders)
{
     AdoNetAppender adoAppender = appender as AdoNetAppender;
        if (adoAppender != null)
           {
               adoAppender.ConnectionString = new conn string;
           }                               
}
```

However, in order to get the logger (first line of the code sample), the logger tries to connect using the default connection string ans hence throws an exception.

Is there any other way to get the appender string so that I don't have to connect before modifying the string?

Answer (score 5):

After messing with it a bit (referring to this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834884/log4net-with-adonetappender-nothing-happens) and this [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/drnetjes/archive/2005/02/16/374780.aspx)), it looks like the `<connectionString>` setting under the AdoNetAppender in the app.config needs to be removed, and a `<connectionType>` setting needs to be added (if it's not already there):

```
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection,
          System.Data, 
          Version=4.0.0.0, 
          Culture=neutral, 
          PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

Then you can modify the connection string in the code:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy hier = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository() as log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy;

if (hier != null)
{
    var adoAppender = (AdoNetAppender)hier.GetAppenders()
                        .Where(appender => appender.Name.Equals("AdoNetAppender", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (adoAppender != null)
    {
        adoAppender.ConnectionString = connstring;
        adoAppender.ActivateOptions(); //refresh settings of appender
    }
}

ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("test");
log.Info("Test Message");
```

Another alternative, if the connection string is under the `<connectionString>`'s in the app.config file, then you can add the following to your appender:

```
<connectionStringName value="ConnectionStringNameFromAppConfig" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply !The problem is that I have other db connections that uses the db connection string. So, I cannot remove the connection string from my app.config.

Comment: @user1748213, I meant that the `<connectionString>` key under the appender configuration needs to removed. I've updated the answer for clarification.

Comment: With this change I am getting an error                    log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] Could not open database connection []
System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: @user1748213, that was a small downside to removing the `<connectionString>` parameter. That should only be in the log4net internal logging errors. What this does is attempts to load the appender, fails, then you change the connection string, call `ActivateOptions()`, and it will use the correct connection string and log properly. I'm not seeing another way to access the AdoNetAppender without loading it first (unless you create it manually).