# Logging messages to different databases

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I'm very new to Log4Net. Please help me understand some concepts.

In my application, I have a single logger. I would like to log messages to different databases based on some conditional logic.

In app config file, I have a logger routing to an AdonetAppender

```
<log4net>
<appender name="SQLAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">     
   <connectionType value="" />
   <connectionString value="" />
</appender
<logger name="AuditLogger">
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="SQLAppender"/>
</logger>
</log4net>
```

Is there a way to set the connection string dynamically via code?

My logger class is designed to be a singleton. I would like to know how the appenders are instantiated. Are they instantited once per logger instance creating or are they instantiated once for every single call to ILog.Info(obj) method call?

Thanks.

Comment: yes there is a way ..do a google search on this `c# log4net set connection string programmatically` also read some previously posted solutions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962870/modify-loggers-adoappender-connectionstring

Comment: @MethodMan, I tried googling and found that we can generate connection string programmatically. But I want a connection string generated dynamically for every call to ILog.Info(obj) method. I didn't find any source that has stated that its possible to do it the way I wanted.

Comment: why can't you store the different database connection strings in the web.config file, then do it that way along with the link that was sent.. and when you say you want it generated dynamically what are you using as a mechanism to determine where to connect..? this can also be done

Comment: We have multiple clients that use our application. Every client uses the same code base. The only thing that changes is the connection string value based on the client. Based on the client that's sending the request, I need to log information in different databases and hence have to resolve the connection string value at runtime for the adonet appender.

Comment: is there anywhere in the application that the client does to connect to the application initially..? if so then track their connection string based on their login or some other unique identifier is this a web application..? if so can you not take advantage of Session variables we have multiple clients that use a single base web application that I maintain and I get their information based on a User Identity If I knew how you are allowing them to connect to your app initially I could probably recommend a better solution show your code on how they are connecting

Comment: The problem is the Logger class is instantiated once for the entire application. I'm not sure if the adonetappender connection string needs to be resolved once per Logger instance or is it okay to change connection string for every call to ILog.Info(). The best way I think is to test these 2 scenarios myself and see whats happens. Thanks for the help MethodMan.

Comment: you can create new instances of that can you not..? could that logger class functionality be put into it's own public and or static class..? I think this can easily be done if you separate the core functionality out into it's own Helper class or create a Utils class that handles this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Every client uses the same code base. The only thing that changes is
>   the connection string value based on the client.

To me this is not 100% clear, I read this as 2 possible scenarios and so 2 possible solutions based on your configuration.

### Multiple deployments

No custom code is really necessary because your deployment should know what the database is that it is working on/with. Based on that you need only configure your AdoNetAppender once on initialization. I assume that it is not this simple because you mention you got this to work in your comments.

### Multitenant Application

You have a single deployment for all your customers and the code figures out the target database based on the origin of the request.

1. I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to create a custom [log4net appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.IAppender.html). The existing [AdoNetAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html) is not sealed so you can inherit from this and override it. You then need to override the protected method `ResolveConnectionString` with your own code where you resolve the connection string based on the execution or request context. *Thank you @stuartd for the pointer on ResolveConnectionString.*
2. You can create your own custom version of the `AdoNetAppender` that has a dynamic database connection string. The only other moving part would be assigning it based on the context as you don't mention how you determine this (or what this context even is, maybe a URL if its a web app?).

Once you have created your appender just add it to the `.config` file (or configure it programmatically if you prefer not to use a config file).

Comment: Subclassing the AdoNetAppender and overriding [ResolveConnectionString](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.ResolveConnectionString.html) should be enough.

Comment: Thank you @stuartd, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I think it would also need to be used in conjunction with a one-logger-per-client policy as well, so there is one logger per thread/request/form/etc (noting that OP has an _app_ config)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Igor for suggesting few ways to resolve connection string.

However, I'm doing something like this.

```
var loggerRepo = LogManager.GetRepository();
if (loggerRepo != null) {
var appender = loggerRepo.GetAppenders().OfType < AdoNetAppender > ().First(a => a.Name == "YourAppenderName");

appender.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ConnectionString;
appender.ActivateOptions();
}
_log.Info("LogSOmeth9ng");
```