# Log4Net with SQLServer database in AspnetCoreBoilerPlate

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, log4net, aspnetboilerplate

I am working in aspnetcore boilerpalte project. I want to save logs in database using log4net. These are my settings of app.config file are as follows.

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="server=.; Database=RBCSDb; User Id=sa; Password=sigma; Integrated Security=false" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date"/>
    <dbType value="DateTime"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="50"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="4000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="2000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

I have created Log table with same parameter with codefirst. And my controller code is like this.

```
Controller class level: 
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);  
Method Level: 
        log.Debug("log Debug");
        log.Info("log Info");
        log.Warn("log Warn");
        log.Error("log Error");
        log.Fatal("log Fatal");
```

After executing code no record inserted in database log table. I don't know where i am wrong. Any solution?

Comment: Any exception logged?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834884/log4net-with-adonetappender-nothing-happens

Comment: No. Your referenced solution did not work. Nor below given answer works. Log table is not being updated even i made each effort.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use ILogger?

```
using Castle.Core.Logging; //1: Import Logging namespace

public class TaskAppService : ITaskAppService
{    
    //2: Getting a logger using property injection
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public TaskAppService()
    {
        //3: Do not write logs if no Logger supplied.
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;
    }

    public void CreateTask(CreateTaskInput input)
    {
        //4: Write logs
        Logger.Info("Creating a new task with description: " + input.Description);

        //TODO: save task to database...
    }
}
```

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Logging

**Sample log4net xml configuration for sql server**

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender_SqlServer" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=SQLSVR;initial catalog=test_log4net;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%thread" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%logger" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message" />
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html